# How to apply stroke when drawing with shape tool (vector)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

With marquee tool selection, I can go to `Edit -> Stroke` to render outline style.
If I wanna do the same with vector shape tool, `Stroke` option is disabled and by default it fills the whole selection. Is there a way I can use `Stroke` with vector shape tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Preventing your shape from being filled

To prevent a shape from being filled, you can enable **Paths** mode in the top toolbar (you probably have *Shape layer* mode enabled).

[image: paths mode]

### Applying a stroke to a path

You can apply a brush stroke to a path from the **Paths** panel, it's the button with the unfilled solid circle icon:

[image: paths panel]

This will draw the stroke with the current Brush Tool settings on the currently selected layer.

An alternative method is to right click on the path and select ***Stroke Path...***

[image: stroke path]

This will give you a few alternatives to stroke it with something other than a brush:

[image: stroke options]

Further reading: [**Stroke paths with color**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7377a.html#WS5801A774-A870-4499-BC12-53144D5B8ACEa)